# Pig nested foreach in Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-pig, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a Pig script into a Spark 2 routine.

Within a `groupBy` I want to compute the number of elements that match particular states. The PIG code looks like that :

```
A = foreach (group payment by customer) {
    done = filter payment by state == 'done';
    doing = filter payment by state == 'doing';
    cancelled = filter payment by ETAT == 'cancelled';
    generate group as customer, COUNT(done) as nb_done, COUNT(doing) as nb_doing, COUNT(cancelled) as nb_cancelled;
};
```

I would like to adapt this to a dataframe starting like `payment.groupBy("customer")`.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out something similar:

Assume the customer table is register in spark session with below schema:

```
 customer.registerTempTable("customer");
 sparkSession.sql("describe customer").show();

+--------+---------+-------+
|col_name|data_type|comment|
+--------+---------+-------+
|      id|   string|   null|
|   state|   string|   null|
+--------+---------+-------+
```

**--Group using map**

```
sparkSession.sql("select id, count(state['done']) as done," +
                "count(state['doing']) as doing," +
                "count(state['cancelled']) as cancelled 
              from (select id,map(state,1) as state from customer) t group by id").show();
```

Comment: Well thanks it did do the job. I found out another solution using aggregate methods like that :
`.groupBy("customer").agg(count(when($"state"==="done"),lit(1))).alias("done"))`